# Scala: what is the most appropriate data structure for sorted subsets?

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming

Given a large collection (let's call it 'a') of elements of type T (say, a Vector or List) and an evaluation function 'f' (say, (T) => Double) I would like to derive from 'a' a result collection 'b' that contains the N elements of 'a' that result in the highest value under f. The collection 'a' may contain duplicates. It is not sorted.

Maybe leaving the question of parallelizability (map/reduce etc.) aside for a moment, what would be the appropriate Scala data structure for compiling the result collection 'b'? Thanks for any pointers / ideas.

Notes:

(1) I guess my use case can be most concisely expressed as

```
val a = Vector( 9,2,6,1,7,5,2,6,9 ) // just an example
val f : (Int)=>Double = (n)=>n      // evaluation function
val b = a.sortBy( f ).take( N )     // sort, then clip
```

except that I do not want to sort the entire set.

(2) one option might be an iteration over 'a' that fills a TreeSet with 'manual' size bounding (reject anything worse than the worst item in the set, don't let the set grow beyond N). However, I would like to retain duplicates present in the original set in the result set, and so this may not work.

(3) if a sorted multi-set is the right data structure, is there a Scala implementation of this? Or a binary-sorted Vector or Array, if the result set is reasonably small?

Comment: What operations should the collection be optimized for?

Comment: @Jesper for the collection 'b': O(logN) insertion, O(1) last and first element, O(1) size. I guess a wrapper for Vector with binary sorting might do the trick, since I expect the result set to be relatively small (maybe N=100 elements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a priority queue:

```
def firstK[A](xs: Seq[A], k: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) = {
  val q = new scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[A]()(ord.reverse)
  val (before, after) = xs.splitAt(k)
  q ++= before
  after.foreach(x => q += ord.max(x, q.dequeue))
  q.dequeueAll
}
```

We fill the queue with the first `k` elements and then compare each additional element to the head of the queue, swapping as necessary. This works as expected and retains duplicates:

```
scala> firstK(Vector(9, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5, 2, 6, 9), 4)
res14: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(6, 7, 9, 9)
```

And it doesn't sort the complete list. I've got an `Ordering` in this implementation, but adapting it to use an evaluation function would be pretty trivial.

Comment: this is very elegant. I ended up modifying two aspects relative to your code, though: instead of xs.splitAt() I now fetch an iterator and traverse it in two stages (analogous to your before and after); without that I had problems with memory allocation for large Iterables. Then instead of q.dequeue I use q.head to test first whether a dequeue is necessary, which gave me a bit of a speedup (>2x). Thanks!

Comment: I've made a slight change to the last line that might give a bit more of an improvement. You shouldn't need to sort the heap, and I only stuck the `sorted(ord)` on the end because—to my surprise and apparently [against the specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.html)—the output of `q.iterator`, etc. wasn't ordered. `q.dequeueAll` works as expected, though.

Comment: .dequeueAll  is better. It also took me a while to realize that the order promised by .iterator, .toList and .toString is not what you actually get. I'll file a ticket.

Comment: The documentation for `iterator` is incorrect and not up-to-date. The iterator is not supposed to respect any order.

Comment: @axel22 right, I presume it was you who commented on the ticket already. :-) Anyway, here is the ticket, just FYI. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5085

Comment: Yes, it was me. These kind of things always seem to manage to sneak through. Thanks!