# In Scala, what is the right way to sort a list on a composite key

Tags: algorithm, list, scala, sorting, composite-key

I am trying to fetch top N-1 elements from a List. I have gone through similar posts in SO, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674741/simplest-way-to-get-the-top-n-elements-of-a-scala-iterable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274726/top-n-items-in-a-list-including-duplicates). I have understood the motivations behind the solutions proposed in those posts. However, I think my problem is a bit different.

I have a sorted (descending) list of some elements. Let's assume that it has been sorted in an efficient manner, because that is not the point here.

The **head** is the topmost that I have got. But, there are 0 or more duplicates in the rest of the list. The *attr1* of each of these duplicates is the same as that of **head**. I want to extract these duplicates (if any). Then I want to sort this (top + duplicates) list on the second attribute, *attr2*. In other words, I want to sort on a composite key: first by Key_1, and then - for the same Key_1 - by Key_2.

Let's say that an element in the list is a Pair.

```
case class PairOfAttrs(val int attr1,val int attr2)

/* .. more code here ... */

// Now, we obtain a sorted (descending) list of PairOfAttrs below
// Ordering is based on the value of attr1 (key_1)
val sortedPairsFirstAttr = .. // Seq(Pair1,Pair2,Pair3,Pair4....Pairn)

val top = sortedPairsFirstAttr.head
```

Obviously, top's attr1 is the highest in the list. To extract the duplicates, I do:

```
val otherToppers = sortedPairsFirstAttr.tail.filter 
                   (e => e.attr1 == topper.attr1) // Expression(1)
```

This is the key point, IMHO. I cannot find the duplicates until isolate the top and use its attribute (*attr1*) during the comparison.

```
// Then, I create a new list of the toppers only

val semiToppers = if (!otherToppers.empty) {
                        List(topper) ++ otherToppers // Expression(2)
                  }
```

Then, I sort the resultant list. Ordering is based on the value of attr2 (Key_2)

```
val finalToppers = semiToppers.sortWith(_._2 < _.2) // Expression(3)
```

So, effectively, I have sorted the original list using a compound key: sorted descendingly on Key_1 and *then*, ascendingly on Key_2.

I understand that *Experssion(1)* can be optimized for a long list; I don't need to travel through the entire list. I can break out of it earlier. I also understand that *Expression(2)* and *Expression(3)* can be merged. So, we can keep these two points aside.

My question is if my approach is functionally appropriate and acceptable. If not, then what you think is a better, more idiomatic approach?

This is a learner's question. So, I seek your comments/observations wholeheartedly.

Comment: The caveats in your question and constraints you place on the answers, leave little room for suggestions. Code is purpose-built, perhaps you could rephrase the question in a way that draws out its purpose.

Comment: @DaveSwartz, could you please point out the caveat in my question? I am ready to do anything that helps in getting the right, appropriate, precise answer!

Comment: One is "Let's assume that it has been sorted in an efficient manner, because that is not the point here.". Another is: "I understand that Experssion(1) can be optimized...". You question should be stated earlier, it takes until near the end of the post to get to your question: "if my approach is functionally appropriate and acceptable. I would also suggest leaving more room for suggestion by providing more context. "If not, then what you think is a better, more idiomatic approach?". The question is also fairly subjective. Suggest you use http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @DaveSwartz, I had put those two (caveats quoted by you) intentionally, to help others, by _not spending time_ on which were foreknown to me. It seems that this has not had the desired effect. However, I accept the point that I could have put the primary question right at the top. Also, I see that the way the question was posed, could have been different, although I must add here that in the past, I have asked questions in similar fashions on SO and got very useful answers. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is working and valid, so I won't comment on it. You already use `val` and immutable data structures, which is the pure way of doing it. 
I will instead suggest an alternative way that is a *slightly* shorter and might also interest you:

Since you preprocess your list anyway, I suggest you to sort it [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) in the first place: First by descending *attr1*, and in case of a tie, by ascending *attr2*:

```
scala> val originalList = Seq((1,0), (2,7), (3,1), (1,3), (2,5), (3,4), (3,2))
scala> val lst = originalList.sortBy(x => (-x._1, x._2))
lst: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((3,1), (3,2), (3,4), (2,5), (2,7), (1,0), (1,3))
```

Now you just have to take the duplicates from the front and the result is already sorted by *attr2*:

```
scala> lst.takeWhile(_._1 == lst.head._1)
res8: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((3,1), (3,2), (3,4))
```

Comment: in addition to your comments and suggestion, I also **thank you** for leading me to learn more about _sortBy_ and then, _Ordering_ where Tuples' fields can be used for tailor-made sorting! Great stuff. One learns every day! (Not sure why your name prefixed by '@' is not showing up properly, I am not an expert in SO, sorry).

Comment: @Nirmalya Glad to help. Stack Overflow let's you not address me via @ because I will be notified anyway if my answer is commented :P Stack Overflow is pretty clever.